# Get text and insert in css styles

Tags: javascript, jquery

good afternoon. Please someone can help me to do this with jquery.
I want to convert this:

```
<li class="li-class">
    <input class="class-radio" name="radio_1" value="red_0" id="id-radio" tabindex="1" type="radio">
    <label for="id-radio"></label>
<label for="id-radio"><span class="span-color">red</span></label>
</li>
<li class="li-class">
    <input class="class-radio" name="radio_1" value="blue_0" id="id-radio" tabindex="2" type="radio">
    <label for="id-radio"></label>
<label for="id-radio"><span class="span-color">blue</span></label>
</li>
```

In this:

```
<li class="li-class">
    <input class="class-radio" name="radio_1" value="red_0" id="id-radio" tabindex="1" type="radio">
    <label for="id-radio"></label>
<label for="id-radio"><span class="span-color" style="color:red">red</span></label>
</li>
<li class="li-class">
    <input class="class-radio" name="radio_1" value="blue_0" id="id-radio" tabindex="2" type="radio">
    <label for="id-radio"></label>
<label for="id-radio"><span class="span-color" style="color:blue">blue</span></label>
</li>
```

If you look, I wish to make the text that goes between the tags are added as the color value in styles...

Here is a picture to explain better

[Click to open Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhAIM.jpg)

Thank you all for your kind help

Comment: What makes you think jquery is the correct tool?

Comment: do you want to toggle the color insertion based of radio button check state?

Comment: What have you tried?  jQuery has a handy `.prop()` function for adding/editing properties on an element.

Comment: @David I would prefer using the `.css()` function for this, as it is a CSS property.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to change the style when you click, here is my snippet (The IDs must be unique, so i rearranged them):

```js
$(function () {
  $(':radio[name="radio_1"]').on('change', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('.li-class').find('.span-color').attr('style', function(index, attr) {
      return 'color:' + this.textContent;
    });
    
    $(this).closest('.li-class').siblings().find('.span-color').removeAttr('style');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<li class="li-class">
    <input class="class-radio" name="radio_1" value="red_0" id="id-radio1" tabindex="1" type="radio">
    <label for="id-radio1"></label>
    <label for="id-radio1"><span class="span-color">red</span></label></span>
</li>
<li class="li-class">
    <input class="class-radio" name="radio_1" value="blue_0" id="id-radio2" tabindex="2" type="radio">
    <label for="id-radio2"></label>
    <label for="id-radio2"><span class="span-color">blue</span></label></span>
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I am looking to have colors colored circles in the radio button label, but wordpress does not allow me to put classes within span tags.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the snippet I've attached.

```js
window.onload = function() {

 var  spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
 var colors = [].slice.call(spans).map(e=> e.innerHTML);
  
  for(var i=0; i<spans.length; i++) {
    spans[i].style.color = colors[i];
}

}
```

```html
<li class="li-class">
    <input class="class-radio" name="radio_1" value="red_0" id="id-radio" tabindex="1" type="radio">
    <label for="id-radio"></label>
<label for="id-radio"><span class="span-color">red</span></label>
</li>
<li class="li-class">
    <input class="class-radio" name="radio_1" value="blue_0" id="id-radio" tabindex="2" type="radio">
    <label for="id-radio"></label>
<label for="id-radio"><span class="span-color">blue</span></label>
</li>
   <li class="li-class">
    <input class="class-radio" name="radio_1" value="green_0" id="id-radio" tabindex="2" type="radio">
    <label for="id-radio"></label>
<label for="id-radio"><span class="span-color">green</span></label>
</li>
   <li class="li-class">
    <input class="class-radio" name="radio_1" value="brown_0" id="id-radio" tabindex="2" type="radio">
    <label for="id-radio"></label>
<label for="id-radio"><span class="span-color">brown</span></label>
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you, your code if it works as I want to, but does not work when applied to wordpress, it seems to me that the radio button input are also generated with jquery

Comment: i don't think it is a difficult problem to make it work on wordpress, i can help you if you want. just didn't get the last one. what is the mechanism they are generated? a button click or what? i